# Is it possible to format on-sheet controls for AWS Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a dashboard with a single visual and several controls for the visual.  There is a LOT of whitespace around the controls, and I'd like to make them more compact. Is it possible to change anything other than the font of the control title?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the white space between controls by creating a [Custom Theme](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/themes-in-quicksight.html) and then selecting the layout option which allows you to turn on or off borders margins or gutters.